# Shift textview to next line if view boundary is reached

Tags: android, android-xml

I have the following layout wrapped inside a linearlayout:

```
<LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <Lato_TextView
                                android:id="@+id/person_name"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:maxLines="2"
                                android:text="Aadil Holy"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                exaprojects:fontName="Lato-Regular.ttf" />

                            <Lato_TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
                                android:layout_marginStart="05dp"
                                android:gravity="start|center"
                                android:text="(#884)"
                                android:textSize="14sp"
                                exaprojects:fontName="Lato-LightItalic.ttf" />
                        </LinearLayout>
```

The views are laid in horizontal alignment inside a cardview, the problem here is if the text in `person_name` is too long, the text in `textView2` gets clipped and is shown vertically, which runs this layout. How to overcome this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using RelativeLayout instead. Example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/person_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="Aadil Holy"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="05dp"
        android:gravity="start|center"
        android:text="(#884)"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Comment: While this is an effective solution, I want the second textview stick to the end of `person_name` text view.

Comment: textview2 is currently at the end of person_name. You mean the second textview is below of person_name?

Comment: I am talking about this attribute of `textView2` `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` I would want it to be `android:layout_toRightof`

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea. The result of that will be the same of using LinearLayout since textview2's width is impressed by person_name's width. Why do you want that?

Comment: if this answer resolved your problem, could you up-vote it please?

Answer (score 0):

First approach:

```
android:ems or setEms(n)
```

"Makes the TextView be exactly this many ems wide"

Note : but only when the layout_width is set to "wrap_content". Other layout_width values override the ems width setting.

You can also try this:

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

Comment: ems should be set on the longer textview?

Comment: With ems you will always get the same width, no metter how long the text. And yes you should apply it to textview, in xml or programtically.

Comment: Can also try to put 
    android:minWidth
to textView2

Comment: ems is completely destroying my layout